# Extract id style from html page using Html agility pack

Tags: c#, html, css

I have a c# application. I need to extract data from a html page and add it to my database. The html page contains some css code and I am interested in all of the id's attributes from the css. How can I pull out the id's info into my code? I tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var styles = document.DocumentNode.SelecNodes("//style");
foreach(HtmlNode node in styles)
{
   var text = node.Attributes["id"];
}
```

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, access Id property directly :

```
var styles = document.DocumentNode.SelecNodes("//*[@style]");
foreach(HtmlNode node in styles)
{
   var text = node.Id;
}
```

**Edit:**  expression changed to "//*[@style]" which gets you only elements with style attribute.

Comment: what did you use ... //@style or //style ? also where you are getting error ?

Comment: This time I used //@style and I am not receiving any error. The only problem is that it grabs some string from some other div's, not from where I need it to.

Comment: expression changed to "//*[@style]" which gets you only elements with style attribute, check updated code now.

Answer (score 0):

More of a fishing rod than a fish, but that's all I got time to do ATM.

First, look at this tutorial: [xpath on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp). I've done some work with XPath, and it was only after going through their tutorial that things started to make a bit of sense.

Then, please get this [html agility test pack](https://htmlxpathtestbed.codeplex.com/), it will let you quickly test your code against the page you're trying to parse.

From here, it should be a short way to get what you want.